# Timer, timezone, server side time, client side countdown

Tags: php, javascript, time, timezone

I've launch a project recently [(here)](http://www.wriiite.com/), and I'm stuck with a timer/time question :

I have a cronjob who runs everyday, twice a day : midnight and midday in french timezone.

I want to display a "countdown till next page", which is in fact a countdown till cronjob.

I'm a bit stuck, because when I start to think time and timezone related things, my brain just freeze.

I know I should take server side time, and display my variables in a client side timer (without getting the client side time), but that's pretty much it.

I'd really appreciate some advises !

Thanks in advance to all of you !

Comment: The class `DateTime` (or, even better, [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) for PHP 5.5+) allows you to create values that represent a specific moment in time. You can directly compare two of them with `<` to find which is earlier. The [`diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method allows you to find the interval between two such moments. Have you tried using them?

Comment: I'm not sure my host has php greater than 5.4, so I'll have to stick with dateTime !
I know the diff method, but how can I have this specific "midnight" or "midday" is what keep me stuck...

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `DateTime` for this.

- The current time
- The midday time
- The midnight time

Here is an example.

```
$now = new DateTime;
$morning = new DateTime('08:00');
$night = new DateTime('22:00');
// next time is night
if( $now > $morning && $now < $night )
{
    $time = $now->diff($night);
} 
// next time is day
else 
{
    $time = $now->diff($morning);

}

$target = $time->format('%h:%i:%s'); // returns a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Keith Wood's countdown timer: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

It is extremely easy to use.

All you have to do is

```
$('#timer').countdown({
    until: '<?php echo date("h:i:s"); ?>' // change this, obviously
});
```

**Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqyj4/289/**