# PHP daily countdown timer server side

Tags: php, timer

I have a question about a php code i took from an answer:
[Timer, timezone, server side time, client side countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733345/timer-timezone-server-side-time-client-side-countdown)
I modified the php code for my own usages:

```
$now = new DateTime;
$Boss1 = new DateTime('07:50');
$Boss2 = new DateTime('11:50');
$Boss3 = new DateTime('23:50');
// next time is night
if( $now > $Boss1 && $now < $Boss2)
{
    $time = $now->diff($Boss2);
} 
// next time is day
else
if( $now > $Boss2 && $now < $Boss3) 
{
    $time = $now->diff($Boss3);

}
else 
{
    $time = $now->diff($Boss1);

}

$target = $time->format('%h:%i:%s');
echo "<b>Next Boss Fight:</b> " . $target;
```

At this moment, he only goes down in time when you refresh the page.
Here can you have a look on the page (it is for mobile use):
[My Website](http://www.novalirium.com/river)
Only now i wondering, how do i let it countdown without refreshing the page?

Comment: not possible only via php, use javascript

Comment: just download some js library to do that for you

Comment: You could poll the PHP script with Ajax to update it at a regular interval, you could use event source /server sent events to create a "session", you could/should use a javascript plugin to manage these times for you client side to reduce server load, or a combination of the above